# How to allow just one site to use PHP's exec() function

Tags: php, apache-2.4

I have a simple Apache with mod_php server on CentOS 7. I've disabled the exec function in php.ini but I need to use it on one Vhost. Now obviously I know I can't use multiple php.ini files and I know I can't change the disable_functions setting outside of the php.ini file, so I tried toying with other ideas.

Obviously my first option was to use fastcgi, or suPHP, etc. but I couldn't get them to work without breaking the server, and whilst I probably could eventually make them work, I'd rather find a different solution and stick with the simple mod_php.

My second thought was to install Nginx and php-fpm and get it to listen on another port, but despite setting disable_functions to an empty value, it still read the php.ini file as well and thus disabled the php_exec function.

So is there a relatively simple way of achieving this without having to reset up Apache with fastcgi?

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/541777/disable-php-functions-per-website) for some ideas.  That method would require you disabling functions in all except for 1 virtualhost.

Comment: Suhosin works an absolute treat! Ta, @Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have a pretty good answer, thanks to pointers from [Aaron](https://serverfault.com/users/261951/aaron)

Install Suhosin using [this](http://www.tecmint.com/protect-php-installation-with-suhosin-security-patch-in-rhel-centos-fedora/)

> yum install php-devel
>
> wget http://download.suhosin.org/suhosin-0.9.33.tgz
>
> tar -xvf suhosin-0.9.33.tgz
>
> cd suhosin-0.9.33
>
> phpize
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install
>
> echo 'extension=suhosin.so' > /etc/php.d/suhosin.ini
>
> service httpd restart
>
> yum install php-devel
>
> yum install php-suhosin

Add this to the bottom of `php.ini` file (a list of functions to blacklist):

```
suhosin.executor.func.blacklist = “exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source”
```

Finally, to the VirtualHost that should be allow to use the disabled functions, add this:

```
php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist =
```

Suhosin forces a script to exit when it reaches a function that is blacklisted, rather than ignoring the function like the native disable functions setting.